# Can I implement a Maker/Checker bot with Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to create a Maker/Checker Bot with Microsoft Bot Framework Nodejs SDK for Microsoft Teams?

SCENARIO:

- X= MAKER
- Y= CHECKER
- Z= BACKEND

Say X wants to onboard a new customer, X will fill in the customer information on the chatbot, the bot will inform Y about the action as presented in this image.
[image]

**If  Y approves the action, The bot will then send the data to the backend(Z).**
**If Y rejects the action, the bot will inform X that their action was rejected.**

Is this possible at all? Please help with documentation if yes is the answer.

Comment: Hi @Folorunso Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/up-to-date-views) it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be fine

Suggest to use

- a [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/create-task-module?tabs=dotnet) for X to provide input
- [Approvals in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/teams/native-approvals-in-teams) to handle the approval flow.

In fact , as you use the term 'Makers', I think you should be able to set this up using [Dataverse for Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/teams/overview-data-platform) and an Power Automate workflow, which could be used by anyone having a Teams License, and much quicker to build.